# Get label pop up on active layer only

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, wfs

I have this layer from Geoserver which I overlay in PNG Format on my leaflet map:

```
/////  Geoserver Layers in WMS format 
var pop_tot = L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8081/geoserver/cite/wms", {
    layers: 'cite:vnm_polbnda_adm3_2014_pdc',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    version: '1.1.0',
    attribution: "test"
});
```

I do have also this part of code to display the labels when I click on my polygons.

```
///// Add base layers + layers geoserver


    L.control.layers(baseLayers,overlays).addTo(map);

            /// Popup limite_inter_district
                var owsrootUrl = 'http://localhost:8081/geoserver/cite/wms';
                var defaultParameters = {
                    service : 'WFS', 
                    version : '2.0',
                    request : 'GetFeature',
                    transparent: false,
                    typeName : 'cite:vnm_polbnda_adm3_2014_pdc',
                    outputFormat : 'json',
                    format_options : 'callback:getJson',
                    SrsName : 'EPSG:4326'
                };
                var parameters = L.Util.extend(defaultParameters);
                var URL = owsrootUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parameters);
                var ajax = $.ajax({
                    url : URL,
                    dataType : 'json',
                    jsonpCallback : 'getJson',
                    success : function (response) {
                    L.geoJson(response, {
                      style: function(feature) {
                        return {stroke: false, fillOpacity: 0.0};
                      },
                            onEachFeature: function (feature, url) {
                                popupOptions = {maxWidth: 250};
                                url.bindPopup("<b>Adm3 Name:</b> " + feature.properties.adm3_name 
                                    + "<br><b>Total Population: </b>" + feature.properties.pop 
                                    ,popupOptions);
                            }
                        }).addTo(map);
                    }
                });
```

I would like the Pop Up to be active only when my layer pop_tot is selected. How I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the logic of your app correctly, you have GeoJSON layer only for displaying popups. In this case the easiest solution would be to add this layer to the map when `pop_tot` layer is added, and remove it when `pop_tot` layer is removed.

For this purpose `pop_tot` layer's `add` and `remove` events can be used. First one is fired when layer is added to the map and the second one when it is removed. Those events can then be used to add/remove GeoJSON layer when `pop_tot` layer is added/removed.

So your `$.ajax` call can then look something like this:

```
var geoJSON;

var ajax = $.ajax({
  url: URL,
  dataType: 'json',
  jsonpCallback: 'getJson',
  success: function (response) {
    geoJSON = L.geoJson(response, {
      style: function(feature) {
        return {stroke: false, fillOpacity: 0.0};
      },
      onEachFeature: function (feature, url) {
          popupOptions = {maxWidth: 250};
          url.bindPopup("<b>Adm3 Name:</b> " + feature.properties.adm3_name 
              + "<br><b>Total Population: </b>" + feature.properties.pop 
              ,popupOptions);
      }
    }).addTo(map);
    pop_tot.on('add', function(evt) {
      if (!map.hasLayer(geoJSON)) map.addLayer(geoJSON);
    });
    pop_tot.on('remove', function(evt) {
      if (map.hasLayer(geoJSON)) map.removeLayer(geoJSON);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: awesome thanks again for these tips! ''If I understand the logic of your app correctly, you have GeoJSON layer only for displaying popups''. That's correct, I'm still questioning myself... That's probably not the best way to display Popups with leaflet with GeoServer in terms of speed? Any better ways to display the PopUp with Geoserver and leaflet?